# Synology services suddenly don't run anymore

Tags: synology

I have a Synology 213+ running with SabNZBD, Sickbeard and CouchPotatoServer. However, since today(?) these services suddenly don't start anymore. When trying to start these services manually I get the error below:

"Failed to run package service"

Other services like Python, FileBot, Git, Git Server, PHPMyAdmin, and some other (non important) services kept running without any problem. Are there any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: please add more details to the question, OS, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An automatic update to DSM 6 messed up my setup.
The package folders were suddenly owned by root instead of the user I've create when installing. Changing the user in the startup scripts was the solution to my problem. I've used this [forum post](https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=117015) to come to this solution (includes a step-by-step).